# Is there a friendly calling for uncle?

Tags: vocabulary

‘[Auntie](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/auntie)’ seems to be a friendly calling for ‘aunt.’ Then is there the word for ‘uncle’?

Comment: I believe adding name with "Uncle" makes it friendlier.

Comment: In the US, native speakers do not use "Uncle" *without* his proper name, when addressing an uncle. They'd say "Uncle Joe, could you please take a look at this strange coin I found?", not "Uncle, could you please..."  So they might say "Uncle Joey" to make it friendlier.

Comment: The '-y-' is a diminutive ending. But they would have to have used this form all along.  It's not something one does when the relationship is not already very friendly.

Comment: That's interesting @Tᴚoɯɐuo. In Britain, it's quite normal to address an uncle as "Uncle". Also "Auntie"; but not "Aunt", in my experience. _That_ sounds like something out of a nineteenth century book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People sometimes say "Unk". As in, "Hey, unk, come over here!" But this is not as common as "auntie". In modern American usage, I don't think either is very common. We pretty much say "aunt" and "uncle".

Comment: "Auntie" also calls to mind an older, somewhat strange lady... I'm not sure it's necessarily friendly.

Comment: After seeing this [youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyZA81r-9jE), I got the question. The word comes at 8'02"

Comment: @hunter My niece and nephew call me "Auntie Colleen" - I'm pretty sure it's friendly :) It might be a regional thing though. We don't change uncle in the same way though - we just way "Uncle Bob".

Comment: Haha, sorry for overgeneralizing!

Comment: @hunter Actually, I am an older _very_ strange lady. I take offense to the _somewhat_ because I never do anything half way :) Auntie can evoke some "crazy cat lady" or "old maid" images depending on what books, movies, or shows you've seen, but I think if it's used with a name it's different. Here in the South, children are discouraged from calling adults by their first name, so they will put a title in front of the name like "Auntie Colleen" or if the adult isn't a relative "Mr. Bob". It's not as formal as using the last name but not as familiar as using just the first name.

Comment: @colleenv When I was a boy it was common for children to call a close friend of their parents "Aunt Sally" or "Uncle Joe", even when there was no actual family relationship. As you say, not as formal as calling him "Mr Jones" but it's often considered inappropriate for children to address an adult by his first name.

Comment: @Jay The children in our family also used Aunt and Uncle for adult close friends of the family and even older cousins.